# WordPress wp_localize_script : PHP variable not recognized by JS script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to modify a script (**ajaxcalls.js**) in my WordPress via my child theme. I created a duplicate of the file in the child theme (**ajaxcalls_child.js**).

I added the following code inside the **function.php** file in order to dequeue the old JS file, enqueue the new one and pass the variable **`ajaxcalls_vars`** which ajaxcalls_child.js uses:

```
<?php

//made sure here that the action execute after all the other scripts are loaded
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpestate_load_child_scripts', 100);

function wpestate_load_child_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script('wpestate_ajaxcalls');

    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxcalls_child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ajaxcalls_child.js', array('jquery'),'1.0', true);

    wp_localize_script(‘ajaxcalls_child’, ‘ajaxcalls_vars’, array(
        'contact_name'     =>  esc_html__( 'Your Name','wprentals'),
        'contact_email'    =>  esc_html__( 'Your Email','wprentals'),
        'contact_phone'    =>  esc_html__( 'Your Phone','wprentals'),
        'contact_comment'  =>  esc_html__( 'Your Message','wprentals'),
        'adv_contact_name' =>  esc_html__( 'Your Name','wprentals'),
        'adv_email'        =>  esc_html__( 'Your Email','wprentals'),
        'adv_phone'        =>  esc_html__( 'Your Phone','wprentals'),
        'adv_comment'      =>  esc_html__( 'Your Message','wprentals'),
        'adv_search'       =>  esc_html__( 'Send Message','wprentals'),
        'admin_url'        =>  get_admin_url(),
        'login_redirect'   =>  $login_redirect,
        'login_loading'    =>  esc_html__( 'Sending user info, please wait...','wprentals'),
        'userid'           =>  $userID,
        'prop_featured'    =>  esc_html__( 'Property is featured','wprentals'),
        'no_prop_featured' =>  esc_html__( 'You have used all the "Featured" listings in your package.','wprentals'),
        'favorite'         =>  esc_html__( 'Favorite','wprentals').'<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>',
        'add_favorite'     =>  esc_html__( 'Add to Favorites','wprentals'),
        'remove_favorite'  =>  esc_html__( 'remove from favorites','wprentals'),
        'add_favorite_unit'=>  esc_html__( 'add to favorites','wprentals'),
        'saving'           =>  esc_html__( 'saving..','wprentals'),
        'sending'          =>  esc_html__( 'sending message..','wprentals'),
        'reserve'          =>  esc_html__( 'Reserve Period','wprentals'),
        'paypal'           =>  esc_html__( 'Connecting to Paypal! Please wait...','wprentals'),
        'stripecancel'     =>  esc_html__( 'subscription will be cancelled at the end of the current period','wprentals'),
        'max_month_no'     =>  intval   ( get_option('wp_estate_month_no_show','') ),
        'processing'       =>  esc_html__( 'processing..','wprentals'),
        'home'             =>  get_site_url(),
        'delete_account'   =>  esc_html__('Confirm your ACCOUNT DELETION request! Clicking the button below will result your account data will be deleted. This means you will no longer be able to login to your account and access your account information: My Profile, My Reservations, My bookings, Invoices. This operation CAN NOT BE REVERSED!','wprentals'),
        'adv_search_what_half' =>  $adv_search_what_half,
        'adv_search_how_half'  =>  $adv_search_how_half,
        'adv_search_type'      =>  $adv_search_type
    ));
}
```

Now after I visit my website, I can see that the old script has been replaced by the new one but I can see on the chrome console that ajaxcalls_vars is not defined as soon as the a function needs it in the new script.

**Error on the chrome console**

[image: Error on the chrome console]

So the new script is there but my variable **`ajaxcalls_vars`** is not defined according to **ajaxcalls_child.js**, therefore, I think there is something wrong in the way I try to pass that variable to the new script.

After looking at similar issue, I understood other type of mistake and tried to improve that code up to the one I shared above. But still can not get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single quotes around the first 2 args in `wp_localize_script(‘ajaxcalls_child’, ‘ajaxcalls_vars’, array(...` are not real single quotes. Try deleting them and replacing with the `'` character `wp_localize_script('ajaxcalls_child', 'ajaxcalls_vars', array(...`
Once I did that, the object is available in the enqueued script (tested on xampp wp 5.0)

Comment: Indeed this is working now... feeling like a beginner from time to time is the beauty of this community. Thanks a lot!